# Django-Machina forum panel not showing in wagtail admin panel

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a wagtail project being developed, essentially a blog with a forum. I chose django-machina as the forum I want to use because of how modular it is and how well it integrates into existing projects.

I followed the instructions in the documentation without issue, and the install was a success. I can access the app by going to /forum on my project.

However, the next step in the documentation refers to using the forum admin panel. My wagtail admin menu does not have a section for forum and I can't access the django admin panel as it is a wagtail project.

Where exactly can I access the django-machina forum admin panel in a wagtail project? Or would I have to recreate it somehow?

Comment: It would be helpful to give a link to the page of the documentation you're following...

Comment: Jake, why did you choose Django-Machina as forum engine for Wagtail? Have you considered any other alternatives?

Comment: @Suncatcher I did look at the alternatives, and django-machina seemed the best fit my needs. It has ongoing and active development, python 3 support and seemed most like it would integrate best into my site. I'm actually really happy with it so far.

Comment: And what other forums does Wagtail support? I haven't found such info.

Comment: I didn't look for forums with wagtail specific support, just chose ones that worked with python 3. I expected the forum to be pretty separate from the rest of my app...machina is nice because it is easy to customize. All I have to do is change colors and add my navbar and it looks like part of my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the documentation specifically mentions Wagtail, it's more likely that the admin panel shows up in the Django admin backend rather than the Wagtail one. On a standard Wagtail project this is found at the URL `/django-admin/`, but it depends on what you have specified in your project's `urls.py` file.

Comment: Thanks! Had no idea I could still access the django admin.

Answer (score 1):

Jake, it's not so difficult. Let your project be named 'my_project'. So than we should go to my_project/my_project/urls.py. There we see something like this:

```
url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

And what this string say to us? It show how to get the vanilla django-admin! Ok, now just go to `your.site/django-admin` and run your forum! ;)